# How to create divs dynamically based on number of items with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery method where I get a collection of data  If the collection has 2 items I want to create 2 divs, if collection has 5 items I want to create 5 divs.

My snippet is

```
 function fetchOrderData() {
    $(".loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: baseUrl + "GetData",
        data: { JobNo: $("#JobNo").val() }
    }).success(function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $("#datano").html("<strong>data Id: </strong>:" + data.No);
            $("#itmqty").html("<strong>Qty: </strong>:" + data.Quantity);
            $("#price").html("<strong>Price: </strong>:" + data.Price);
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $('.alert-danger').show();
            }
        }
```

My Design Code is :

```
                                    <div class="box4">
                                    <div class="col-md-4" id="datano">
                                        <strong>ItemNo: </strong></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2" id="itmqty">
                                        <strong>Qty: </strong></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3" id="price">
                                        <strong>Price: </strong></div>
                                    <!-- <div class="col-md-2" id="item_status">
                                        Status</div> -->
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itemformedit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">
                                        </span></a>| <a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: What does your data (json) look like?

Answer (score 0):

use json encode to pass it in an array(eg: data) and use a '**for**' loop on success function.

```
for(i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
    $("#datano").html("<strong>data Id: </strong>:" + data[0]);
    $("#itmqty").html("<strong>Qty: </strong>:" + data[1]);
    $("#price").html("<strong>Price: </strong>:" + data[2]);
}
```

Comment: You need to first declare `i` as in `for (var i = 0; .....)` for a legitimate JS script.

Comment: i tried this but not getting...for clarification my design code is pls see my update version